# Create a larger UIView from a smaller UIView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frame, addsubview

I have a screen which has a scrollview. Inside the scrollview, there is a subview which has a button. I want that on clicking the button, a larger subview gets added at the bottom of the screen with width same as the width of the screen.

Now I am facing the following issues at the moment:

1. Getting the height of the screen returns the actual height of the scrollview, but i don't want that, I want the height of the screen on the device since the placement of the subview is independent of the scrollview.
2. While setting frame of the subview to be added, if I put in x coordinate as 0, it references it to the coordinate w.r.t. the subview2 and not the screen.

Refer to the images attached for further clarity:
[image: Before button click]

[image: After Button Click]

On Clicking Button1, Subview3 needs to be added.

**EDIT 1:** In subview2, i am handling the click of the button1. On click, i tried:

```
        subview3.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        self.view.addSubview(subview3)
        subview3.expandFromBottom()
```

Then in **expandFromBottom()**, I have :

```
tableHeightConstraint?.constant = min(CGFloat(self.items.count) * self.itemHeight - 1, UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

    print("before \(self.view.frame)")
    print("before \(self.view.convert(view.frame.origin, to: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow))")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { [unowned self]  () -> Void in
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= (self.tableHeightConstraint?.constant)!
    })
    print("\(self.view.frame)")
    print("\(self.view.convert(view.frame.origin, to: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow))")
```

This printed the following value:

```
before (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0)
before (18.0, 860.0)
(0.0, -155.0, 414.0, 736.0)
(18.0, 550.0)
```

And subview3 is not visible on the screen.

Earlier, I had tried putting 0 as the y coordinate while adding subview3 but that made the view appear from the origin coordinates w.r.t the subview2. Also, earlier I was using UIApplication.shared.keyWindow to get the height of the screen and i was returning height including scrollview's height but that issue seems to be resolved by using UIScreen.main.bounds.

**PS:** In expandFromBottom, i am trying to add the animation of the view coming up from the bottom of the screen.

**PS2:** tableHeightConstraint is for a tableview inside the subview3

Comment: Can you please add some code of what you tried?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, Share some code what you tried and then we can help you...

Comment: Better you can use UITableView. Its easy to manage

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla Please find the code in the edit

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your code. Can you add the entire viewController code?